# Remove string from txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

So basically I want to **delete** string from txt file.

**using fs**

Input Example:

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
```

Delete `string3`

After delete It would be like:

```
string1
string2
string4
```

Comment: You should be able to open the file using FS, find and delete the sample string, and then save the file using FS again.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you give me an example?

Comment: There is a Node module called FileSystem (it comes with Node installation). If you require as `const fs = require("fs")`, you should be opening the file with fs.openFileSync(//put params in here), reading the contents, editing, then saving with fs.WriteFile().

Comment: Here are the documents for the filesystem module: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the text file get the content in a variable then use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

For example

```
var stringContent="Here goes the content of the textFile after read"
 var res=stringContent.replace('string3','');
//write back res to the file or do what ever
```

Answer (score 0):

As **`brk`** answered, `replace` method on string will do the job.

Another way is 
`var a = new Array();
a = string.split("searching_string");
string = a.join("");`

Think it should work. But why do you make it complex when `replace` exists?