# Removing a line from a txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I delete a row from a txt file without empty lines ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzZDA.png)) ([Example2](https://prnt.sc/jflmqm)).For example, I have a file:

```
Hello
Hello2
String
```

After the deletion, the file will be:

```
Hello
Hello2
```

I tried:

```
let removeString = (data, strToRemove, fileName) => {
    let toRemove = data.replace(strToRemove,'');
    fs.writeFile(fileName, toRemove)
};
```

But leaves blank lines.

Comment: this is duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237509/remove-string-from-txt-file/50237669#50237669

Comment: Don't forget to remove the CRLF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.

Comment: the code that is given there also leaves blank lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove one line from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843016/how-to-remove-one-line-from-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you cannot only remove the text as there are carriage return and line feed characters to consider `\r\n`.

If you know the `\r\n` characters always follow the text you can do this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

let strToRemove = 'hello2\r\n';
let fileName = 'test.txt';
fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    let toRemove = data.replace(strToRemove,'');
    fs.writeFile(fileName, toRemove);
});
```

Comment: Your code won't delete first or last line @RyanSearle

Comment: It does, as I've said, this only works if the CRLF follows the text.